# $scope.data.push into json angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, push

I have a form and a json file. I want to push data entered into the form elements and create new json objects within the main array.

```
<html ng-app="example">
    <div ng-controller="ListController">
        <form name="myform" ng-submit="addThis()">
            <input type="text" ng-model="model1">
            <input type="text" ng-model="model2">
        </form>
    </div>
</html>
```

JS:

```
 var app = angular.module('example', []);
 app.controller('ListController', ["$scope", "$http", function($scope) {
     $http.get("_/js/data.json").success(function(data) {
         $scope.mydata = data;
     });
     $scope.addThis = function() {
         $scope.mydata.push({
              model1:$scope.mydata.keyname1,
              model2:$scope.mydata.keyname2
         });
     };
 }]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well a few things

In your js it likes 
1) you didn't close one of the functions properly.

2) you didn't define the scope variables properly, **$scope** (to my knowledge) does not store "name" properties of html objects. You refer to variables stored in the controller scope through html either using the curly brackets or certain ng-tags like ng-model.

3) if you are going to store variables in **$scope.mydata.somevar** make sure to call them from **mydata.somevar**!

JS

```
var app = angular.module('example', []);
app.controller('ListController', ["$scope", "$http", function($scope) { 

 $scope.mydata = { model1: '', model2: ''} ;// initializing the model earlier on (good practice) 

 $http.get("_/js/data.json").success(function(data) { 
    $scope.mydata.data = data; 
 }); //<----- forgot a bracket here! 

 $scope.addThis = function() {  
   $scope.mydata.model1=$scope.mydata.data.keyname1;     
   $scope.mydata.model2 =$scope.mydata.data.keyname2;
 }; 
}]);
```

Html

```
<html ng-app="example">
     <div ng-controller="ListController">     
         <form name="myform" ng-submit="addThis()">
            <input type="text" ng-model="mydata.model1"> 
            <input type="text" ng-model="mydata.model2"> <!--- notice the mydata.model2!! ---->
          </form>
      </div> 
 </html>
```

As a side note, **$http** load things **asynchronously**, if you want to the best of your code consider using [q promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), to organize the flow of your function. 
Or if you want to code to automatically load the json file into the form then have it store the data in **$scope.mydata.model1** and **$scope.mydata.model2** the moment it gets the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips and correction. However, I still couldn't get it to work. I'm thinking that it could have to do with the whole architecture of my software. I'm using ng-include a lot, which means files are storing info autonomously and I feel this might be the heart of the problem.